# Java unmarshal xml with illegal XML characters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm trying to unmarshal with `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` the XML string but received the following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Are there any universal solutions to remove all illegal XML characters from the input string?

For example, I tried to use the following one but it doesn't help:

```
public static String illegalXML11CharactersPattern = "[^"
        + "\u0001-\uD7FF"
        + "\uE000-\uFFFD"
        + "\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff"
        + "]+";

public static String stripNonValidXML11Characters(String xml) {
    return xml.replaceAll(illegalXML11CharactersPattern, "");
}
```

Comment: You need to look over your xml. `0x13` actually is a "carriage return"  perhaps you have it somewhere inside XML tag or attribute. In real there are only five XML invalid characters for XML values: http://keylimetie.com/blog/2008/9/25/how-to-safely-escape-invalid-xml-characters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I finished with the following approach:

```
xml = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(xml));
```

Comment: could you please specify where did you implement the fix?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was so long ago that I don't remember anymore

Comment: This is potentially a simple preparation of the string with XML before any further processing.